# Converting a set of dataframes into a multidimensional array in Julia

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia

[A Julia noob question.]

Let's say I have a vector of dataframes, as below:

```
using DataFrames
A = DataFrame([8.1 9.2 7.5 6.6; 6.9 8.1 6.8 5.8])
B = DataFrame([9.0 2.1 5.2 5.3; 1.2 4.9 9.8 7.7])
dfs = [A, B]
```

Of course, I have actually a much larger number of dataframes in `dfs` than in this MWE, but all of them have the same dimensions, and all of them have only numeric columns.

I would like to transform `dfs` into a multidimensional (here, 2x4x2) array `arr`, with `arr[:, :, 1]` equal to A, and `arr[:, :, 2]` equal to B. How can I perform this transformation? (Of course, a `for` loop might do the trick, but I guess that there is a more elegant way to proceed.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that

```
f1(dfs) = cat(Matrix.(dfs)..., dims=3)
```

is a reasonably elegant one-liner, but it allocates temporaries.

From a speed perspective you can probably beat it easily with the following one-liner

```
f2(dfs) = [ dfs[k][n,m] for n = 1:size(dfs[1],1), m = 1:size(dfs[1],2), k = 1:length(dfs) ]
```

Having said that, if you're willing to be a little more verbose, you can probably do better again using the iteration protocols specifically designed for use with `DataFrame`.

```
function f3(dfs)
    y = Array{Float64,3}(undef, size(dfs[1],1), size(dfs[1],2), length(dfs))
    for k = 1:length(dfs) ; for (n,col) in enumerate(eachcol(dfs[k]))
        y[:,n,k] = col
    end ; end
    return y
end
```

As a general rule, if you want speed in Julia, loops are often the best approach. Let's do a quick comparison of the three approaches:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime f1($dfs);
  182.454 μs (132 allocations: 7.89 KiB)

julia> @btime f2($dfs);
  935.217 ns (21 allocations: 672 bytes)

julia> @btime f3($dfs);
  338.664 ns (11 allocations: 368 bytes)
```

So `f3` is pretty much 6x faster than `f1`. You could throw an `@inbounds` in `f2` and `f3` for further optimization although I suspect it won't gain you that much...

Now, to be fair, I just assumed everything was `Float64` here. However, with a quick type check up front, you can generalise this to any type (as long as it is all one type - which presumably it is given that you're wanting to convert to a single array).

Comment: Many thanks, it's perfect! (Btw: "As a general rule, if you want speed in Julia, loops are often the best approach", thanks for this insight. As an R user, this is a huge shift in coding pratices. ;-))

Comment: @Philopolis I was just messing around and managed to get another significant boost in performance by using iteration protocols specific to dataframes. See updated answer...